# Make custom query from two table access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two table that table 1 contains Number, code, ID and table 2 contains Name, Family name, Number, ID, code, Phone number,...

Now I want to make a query that contains table 2 fields but the query should check that if for example table2 contains  table1.Number, show the table 2 fields that contains Table1.Number and if table2 doesn't contains the Table1.Number, show the table 2 fields but just fill the fields that table1 and table 2 have them and just for example put "-" in the filed Phone number because table1 doesn't has that but it has code field and table 2 has it too so it should be fill it with the table 1 parameter
And this proccess should be continue for all of the codes of table 1

For example:

Table1 has this data

[image: Table1]

Table 2 data

[image: Table2]

Query example:

[image: Result]

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the query designer for a new query.
2. Add the tables you are interested in.
3. Drag the field number from `table1` to `table2`
4. Drag the field code from `table1` to `table2`
5. Right click on each of the lines between the two tables and select `join properties`
6. Select option 2

[image]

7. Lastly in the bottom section of the designer select the columns you wish to see in your output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    [Table1].[Code],
    [Table1].[Number],
    [Table2].[Name1],
    [Table2].[Family]
    ...
FROM [Table1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table2]
ON [Table1].[Code] = [Table2].[Code]
    AND [Table1].[Number] = [Table2].[Number]
```

Being that this is Access, you'll have to check the documentation for the `IIF` statement, for replacing `NULL` values with a `-`.

However, once you create this query, you should then be able to edit it in the designer.